# Олимпиадное программирование, с чего начать?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В январе олимпиада намечается у меня, имеются базовые знания c++, с чего вообще начинать изучение, а то алгоритмов очень много, а что да как и для чего нужно сложно разобраться

Comment: Думаю, с C++. За 4 месяца вы вряд ли успеете столькому обучиться...

Comment: Столькому не надо. Мне не надо сразу задачи с графами, просто для начала мб поиск сортировка и так по нарастающей

Comment: В ЛКШ тоже по порядку дают все, вот мне и интересен этот порядок, просто я не имею возможности туда попасть

Comment: просмотрите типичные олимпиадные задачки, про полиндромы, нахождение подпоследовательностей в последовательностях и т.п., т.к. они постоянно повторяются только формулировки меняются

Comment: посмотри задачи за прошлый год.
И скорей всего вас заставят на Паскале писать

Comment: нет, на паскале не заставят, уже давно разрешен C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу [[@Shad](/users/1560/shad)](/users/1560/shad) добавил бы ссылку на [Сodeforces](http://codeforces.ru/). Вся его прелесть заключается в том, что можно смотреть коды задач других участников и очень грамотные тесты на задачи. Для начала (после регистрации) зайдите во вкладку "Архив" и отсортируйте по количеству решенных человек. И прям с верху списка начинайте решать. Не забывайте смотреть код других участников! Изредка, но можно найти решения использующие "фишки" языка.

Comment: @Ildik Simpson, а как можно посмотреть решение задачи другими учатсниками в разделе "Архив", а то там нету сортировки по названию в разделе "Статус"

Comment: Итак, вы во вкладке "Архив". (думаю, вы разобрались как отсылать свои решения). Чтобы посмотреть решения других участников, нажмите на цифру количества участников решивших эту задачу (последний столбик во вкладке "Архив"). Откроется статистика, справа будет фильтр, можно указать какой язык вы хотите посмотреть. Однако, если вы хотите смотреть решения на С++, то внизу поставьте галочку "Сортировать по времени выполнения", и вам тут же, как ни странно, откроются решения на С++ (немного перемешанные с Паскаль и Делфи). И чтобы посмотреть исходный код, нажмите на ID кода - это первый столбец.

Comment: И добавлю про велосипеды, не всегда можно найти решение написанное с использованием STL. Но они есть и почти всегда хитро реализованы. Если совсем базовые знания, то лучше один-два раза написать самому структуру (для более сложных задач это чаще придется делать). Или же, если вы прекрасно понимаете как примерно оно реализовано - копайтесь и гуглите как это можно реализовать используя STL. Не забывайте про сайт http://www.cplusplus.com/ .

Answer (score 4):

C++ во всей его полноте врядли понадобится, хватит и обычного C.
Я бы начал с алгоритмов целочисленной арифметики:

- поиск делителей числа, простые числа
- поиск НОД, НОК
- системы счисления

Отдельно бы выделил задачи длинной арифметики, когда неоходимо работать с огромными числами, которые не помещаются в стандартные целочисленные типы.
Затем вам понадобится аналитическая геометрия: узнать расстояние между точками, расположение фигуры на плоскости и т.д.
Ещё необходимо понимать алгоритмы сортировки и поиска.

Ну а дальше можно смотреть теорию графов (кратчайший путь, максимальный поток, поиск в глубину/ширину), комбинаторику.

Но просто читать теорию не имеет смысла - надо одновременно и решать задания, чтобы понять как из длинной формулировки выделить суть и определить алгоритм решения.

Посоветую сайт олмпиад по информатике в Беларуси: http://byoi.narod.ru. Большой набор задач за олимпиады прошлых лет + теория.

Comment: А не будет ли он на C вместо решения задач бодаться с изобретением велосипедов в виде реализации давно реализованных структур данных? В тех же крестах которые вполне себе представлены в том же `boost`.

Я, скажем, наверное, в каждом третьем проекте на C вижу собственную реализацию связанных списков. Это, гхм, что-то да явно символизирует.

С одной стороны, один раз, изучая вопрос, сделать свое, скажем, красно-черное дерево это, бесспорно, нужно и полезно, а с другой — делать это в условиях олимпиады выглядит как-то странно.

Comment: По поводу велосипедов - согласен на 100%. Но тут ещё необходимо учесть ограничения и правила проведения олимпиады. Если разрешено использовать бибилотеки с готовыми структурами данных - не вижу причин их не использовать. Но если нет - то придётся крутить педали :)

Answer (score 0):

Начните с [курса олимпиадника](http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=513) на [acmp.ru](http://acmp.ru).